# How to enable `fill-paragraph` command to be executed every time ChatGPT replies via gptel package?

Tags: buffers, hooks, fill-paragraph

I have been using this cool Emacs package called [gptel](https://github.com/karthink/gptel).

However, it is annoying for me how lengthy the ChatGPT answers look on the screen.

When I want to improve readability, I keep executing the `fill-paragraph` command. I would like to have this action performed automatically for the appropriate buffer.

It is worth mentioning that the package creates a separate buffer called `*ChatGPT*` displaying just the questions and the answers.

I tried enabling `auto-fill-mode` on this buffer. But, it did not work out. Here is my [config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el).

How can I achieve my goal? Maybe adding a tailor-made hook?

Comment: Sorry this might not be the most appropriate place to ask. But I wanted to install the package as well. I fetched it with `melpa` using `package-install`. But then the instructions on the github page get weird.. I've created this `~/.authinfo` file and put the credentials of `ChatGPT` there. I'm unsure if I did this right.. I also couldn't run `M-x gptel-send`. Since you've done it already, could you help me figure this out? Would be lovely :)

Comment: Hi @MySQLInjection, you. can "hard code" the api-key. Look at my solution below. You can set the value for the GPT api key. Using `authinfo` is the correct technique concerning safety. But, if you just want to try it out, hard coding the key in the init file is fine.

Comment: Ok I kinda got it working now. However, I get this ChatGPT error: (HTTP/2 429) You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. You probably didn't have this, but if you know how I can troubleshoot this, let me know. Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: Try re-starting Emacs. And try checking your settings in open AI website. Maybe you are using more than your plan allows.

Comment: I opened an issue on github. The owner of the repo already hinted to me, that I might not be able to use it since may because OpenAI disallowed it with all free plans. So probably I can't use the package. I'll wait for his response though. It's a bummer nevertheless. Thanks for providing the code snippet and helping me out. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[trevoke](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/61/trevoke) answer helped me. But, I only managed to achieve the expected result with:

```lisp
(defun clean-gpt-buffer ()
  (with-current-buffer "*ChatGPT*"
    (fill-paragraph)))

(add-hook 'gptel-post-response-hook 'clean-gpt-buffer)
```

Considering that I like [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) declarative approach, this is my code now:

```lisp
;;; Make chatGPT buffer better to read
(defun clean-gpt-buffer ()
  (with-current-buffer "*ChatGPT*"
    (fill-paragraph)))

;;; Use chatGPT inside Emacs
(use-package gptel
 :hook ((gptel-post-response . clean-gpt-buffer)) 
 :config
 (setq gptel-api-key "omitted"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `gptel` has a hook called `gptel-post-response-hook`, so you could do something like this:

```lisp
(defun clean-gpt-buffer ()
  (fill-region (point-min) (point-max)))

(add-hook gptel-post-response-hook 'clean-gpt-buffer)
```

Do note that this is very much the shotgun approach and will use fill paragraph ON THE WHOLE BUFFER, so if you are using gptel in org-mode like in the demo videos I saw in the readme, this would cut long titles in two, etc.

Note that this is untested because I do not use this package.

Comment: Thanks, @trevoke. But, I am having a problem: 
End of file during parsing: /Users/pedro/.emacs.d/init.el

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace. Disable showing Disable logging

Any idea on what could be the problem? I tried adding a quote to `'gptel-post-response-hook`. But, it did not do the trick

Comment: I missed a closing-parens. Fixed it in the answer. It looks like you got something that works for yourself anyway :)